# How to generate an executable file that can run both on macOS and Linux

Tags: linux, macos

I generate an executable file on macOS and now I want to run it on Linux.

I already have my Makefile and I use that to make the executable file on macOS(using gcc). But when I run it on Linux, I got an error message: "./executable: cannot execute binary file". Can anyone help me with solving this problem?

Comment: This is not possible. Create two different executable files.

Comment: You should ask this question in a form that is both a valid English sentence and a valid German sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to compile the executable again on Linux in order to create a binary that runs on Linux.
Unless you setup a cross-compile environment for Linux on MacOSX (using Linux in a Virtual Machine will be easier though), then you could compile for Linux there.

Either way you will end up with 2 different binaries. You can't create a single binary that will run on both Linux and MacOSX.

Comment: Thank you! In that case, do I need to change the Makefile？

Comment: @dongxin Possibly, I have no idea what your Makefile looks like. If it's very simple and basically just calls gcc, then it could work for both.
If it's more complicated than that because e.g. you have to link shared libraries of the system and such, then you might have to change the Makefile so that it finds what it needs on both systems (or make a separate Makefile for each system if you prefer that).

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try then.

Comment: @dongxin You're welcome and good luck :) ps: don't forget to mark your question as answered, so that people know ;)